# Asynchronous Requests with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, webrequest

I am trying to execute an asynchronous request in my MonoTouch application. When I execute the following code, it behaves like the request starts, but it never seems to return. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void StartAsyncRequest()
{
  try
  {
    // Asynchronously execute the query using HttpWebRequest
    string url = GetUrl();
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(AsyncAttempt_Completed), request);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Show error message here.
  }
}

private void AsyncAttempt_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
  try
  {
    // 1. Get the response from the service call
    WebRequest request = (WebRequest)(result.AsyncState);
    using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
    {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
      {
        string temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Show temp value here.
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Show error message here.
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think it does not *return* ? Can you put breakpoint in  your callback ? are they called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have **very** specific requirements I **strongly** suggest you to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) over `WebRequest`. This will handle a lot of things for you *automagically* and will be better (in most cases) wrt memory management.

E.g. most of your code above can be replaced to [`DownloadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202.aspx)

Otherwise your code looks fine. In fact I executed it inside an MonoTouch application and it runs without issue (once `GetUrl` is replaced) and your callback **is** called.

However your comments, not your code, makes me wonder if the call succeed *network-wise* but fails *ui-wise*. e.g.

```
// Show temp value here.
```

The async callback will be called on a different thread. UIKit, like most existing UI toolkit,  requires that all UI-related operations be done on the main (UI) thread. Not doing so will give you a lot of pain.

You can ensure that UI (or other) code is executing on the main (UI) thread by using `InvokeOnMainThread`. See this [article](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/threading) for more details.